# How to map an attribute like Map<Class, AbstractEntity> with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there any possibility with Hibernate to do the following entity structure?

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @OneToMany
    private Map<Class<? extends PersonRole>, PersonRole> personRoles;

    public <T extends PersonRole> T getRole(Class<T> roleClass) {
         return roleClass.cast(roles.get(roleClass));
    }

}

@Entity
public abstract class PersonRole {

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

}
```

Basically Hibernate can persist this mapped entity but it is not possible to load it anymore from the database with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for      collection: de.his.cs.sys.hibernate.Person.roles
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readIndex(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:822)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:277)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:1189)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:804)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:655)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2094)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:61)
```

A workaround could be using a "simple" collection and filling the map with an interceptor, but I hope for a possibility achieving this without additional infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem basically seems to me, that hibernate needs to rely on a persistent attribute for a map key. Therefore the solution adds a new attribute to the abstract class *RersonRole*:

```
private Class<?> className = this.getClass();
```

Then it is possible to refer to it in the @MapKey annotation in the class Person:

```
@OneToMany
@MapKey(name = "className")
private Map<Class<? extends PersonRole>, PersonRole> personRoles;
```

With this mapping hibernate can now fill the Map without further infrastructure.

This from my point of view mostly elegant solution has the drawback of adding a persistent attribute, which is only needed because of hibernate (If I get the root cause of the problem right).

Answer (score 1):

it is possible implementingh a Hibernate `UserType` which maps the class to a string and back

```
@OneToMany
@MapKey(name = "className" type=@Type(type="namespace.classToNameUserType"))
private Map<Class<? extends PersonRole>, PersonRole> personRoles;
```

[see here for an example UserType](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types)

Comment: This alone is not working. But your answer pointed me to a more simple solution: add an attribute "className" of type class to PersonRole and initialize it with getClass(). With that constellation I do not need any UserType. Should I post this as answer?